# Django configuration for errbit

Tags: django, errbit

We would like to send errors from Django application to errbit.

On the web, there is no single example what to put in settings.py of web application.

Could somebody provide what should be done in order to send exceptions from our django application to errbit server?

We investigated with Google, and there is no single example how to do it.

For example, this is configuration for Rails app:
http://blog.8thcolor.com/en/2014/02/get-notified-of-your-rails-app-exceptions-with-errbit/

And all unrescude exceptions will be automatically stored in errbit.

How to configure django application in order to have all unrescued exceptions automatically logged in errbit?

Comment: Not nearly enough information here. Are you using an errbit client in your Django app? How are you configuring it?

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, this is our question. We found several errbit clients. But question is which one to use and how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is link with solution that contains python airbrake implementation that supports python2 and python3.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-airbrake